# Use NSTimer with "let"?

Tags: ios, swift, constants, nstimer, swift2

Hello I'm trying to use NSTimer in a class in Swift 2.0 project. I want to use a `let` constant for time interval, but it always shows the error "string is not convertible to stringLiteralConvertible". When I use a simple number it works, but I need a constant

```
func setupLocationUpdateInterval(seconds: Int)
{
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(seconds, target: self, selector: "startUpdatingLocation", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: Show your code where you're trying to use a let constant so we can see what you tried.

Comment: I need to mention that it is swift 2.0

Comment: The seconds is the constant, it shows same error as if I use let seconds = 10...

Comment: the type of the first parameter of `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` must be `NSTimeInterval` (Double) rather than `Int`

Comment: @vadian As I just stated in my answer below.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers you were given. (It looks like all 3 of us said basically the same thing. (I was first to answer, so if my answer solved your problem I'll gladly take your checkmark. If you think one of the other answers solved your problem where mine did not, by all means, accept that one.) If you don't think any of our answers solved your problem, post an update to your question telling us that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error looks like it's wrong. (The error messages you get from Swift are often totally unrelated to the real cause of the problem, and simply tell you "there's something wrong with this line. Figure out what it is an fix it." That would be better than errors like this, since at least then you wouldn't think the error message was actually providing useful information.)

The `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` method wants an interval value that's a double.

Assuming I am right about the *real* problem, You can either change your function to take seconds as a double, or cast it to a double in your call to `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`.

Comment: @Gibastek and that is why the let line was requested. It is amazing how many times the OP refuses to provide a key piece of requested information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, All I needed to do is to look at type of NSTimeInterval... :D

Comment: @Gibastek Consider accepting answers that are helpful (like this one). 

Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information.

Click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best.  [See this page for more detail](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line:

```
func setupLocationUpdateInterval(seconds: Int)
```

with the line:

```
func setupLocationUpdateInterval(seconds: NSTimeInterval)
```

Or if you want to use a let constant somewhere, make sure its type is `NSTimeInterval`.